# How can I connect to databese (workbench) with the new STS? (3.9.7)

Tags: mysql, database, spring, maven, database-connection

I reinstalled the MySQL like this:

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aY6LiTbfckA

I have the new **JDK 11**.

Its interesting, because the JVM is running, when I click the Run button. But I get an ERROR log, and it doesnt create the table in the workbench:

**ERROR:**

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table name (id bigint not null auto_increment, names varchar(255), primary key (id)) engine=MyISAM" via JDBC Statement
```

**Application properties**

```js
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/?test1=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=adam
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

**I have expanded the pom.xml file with this:** (Before the last  < /dependencies > )

```js
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
            <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
            <version>4.6.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

And finally, I created an Entity package with class.

It contains @Entity, private id (@id, @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)), private name and Getters-Setters with imports.

Thank you for the helps!

Adam